# Upgrade dataset xsd .net 2.0 to .net 4.5

Tags: .net, xsd, dataset, upgrade

I have a class library project which was built on top of the .net framework 2.0.
The project uses some dataset (.xsd files)

I have upgraded the project to .net 4.5, compiled successfully.
But in the run time, I got a security exception (System.Security.SecurityException)

[image]

I figure out that the project after upgraded is targeted for the .net framework 4.5, this causes the exception. When I change back to .net 2.0, it works okay.

But the point here is that I want to target the project to newer version of the .net framework, any idea how to fix it?

I try to follow these tips, but got no luck [Troubleshooting Exceptions: System.Security.SecurityException](https://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev14.query?appId=Dev14IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k(EHSecurity);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework,Version%3Dv4.5);k(DevLang-csharp)&rd=true)

[image]

Comment: Notice that 4.5 is already obsolete version, not supported by Microsoft anymore [https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2015/12/09/support-ending-for-the-net-framework-4-4-5-and-4-5-1/](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2015/12/09/support-ending-for-the-net-framework-4-4-5-and-4-5-1/)

Comment: thank you, the point here if we upgrade to 4.6.2, still get errors, is it?

Comment: any idea please?

Comment: Did you generate your service's client code with new framework version?

Comment: Hi Fabio, no I didn't, how?